# MariaDB remove foreign key to temporary table

Tags: mariadb, concrete5

Context:

I'm trying to upgrade a concrete5 installation from version 8.3.2 to 8.4.1. The upgrade process fails during execution of this SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE AreaLayoutsUsingPresets ADD CONSTRAINT FK_7A9049A1385521EA FOREIGN KEY (arLayoutID) REFERENCES AreaLayouts (arLayoutID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

With:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `concrete5`.`#sql-215_264a4` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")
```

Investigating my database revealed that in `information_schema` in `INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN` there is the following entry:

```
ID                            FOR_NAME                 REF_NAME              N_COLS TYPE
concrete5/FK_7A9049A1385521EA concrete5/#sql-215_26264 concrete5/AreaLayouts    1     5
```

---

Problem:

Now my understanding is, that I cannot modify the `information_schema` as it isn't a database but just a tabular representation of the system.

I'm wondering how do I get rid of that foreign key entry. The table `concrete5/#sql-215_26264` does not exist (I can't find it on my server, nor does `alter table` or `drop table` find that table (I've tried with `#mysql50#` prefix and without it)). So the straight forward way of alter table to drop the foreign key fails because it can't find the table.

I guess I could mess with the upgrade script so that it creates a new foreign key ID, but I'd rather get rid of that zombie in my database. I've already tried to disable the foreign key checks, which then resulted in an error, telling me that the key cannot be added to the system tables (because it's already in there).

Comment: Is concrete5 generating the `FOREIGN KEY`, perhaps indirectly based on something you specify?

Comment: @RickJames the foreign keys are generated during a database upgrade from an older version. I "fixed" the problem with a reinstall using a new database, but I still have those zombie entries in my `information_schema`. I also tried generating the not existing table and delete the foreign key, but that didn't work either (the key was not found)...

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling is rarely a cure for anything; but I am glad that it fixed your situation.

Table names such as `#sql_...` usually come from crashing in the middle of an `ALTER` or similar DDL.  Such *files* can be removed.  `information_schema` is derived from looking at the files, so I think removing the files will kill the zombie entries.

Comment: There are no files to be found starting with `#` anywhere on my server. I still have those zombie entries in my database. Renaming the database didn't remove the zombies either. The entries weren't renamed, so I really am lost as to where these keys are stored.

Answer (score 0):

either prefix the SQL import with `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`

or your append it to your query `ALTER TABLE`...`DISABLE KEYS;`

... and better dump the whole database before messing around.